# Get Latex to follow an arbitrary numbering scheme for figures

Tags: floats, numbering

I'm transcribing the draft of a book with many figures. At this stage, the author
had interpolated some images and eliminated others, so his plate numbers go like
1, 2, 3a, 3b, 3c, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, ... I'd like to preserve his numbering for now.
I've tried various combinations of `\renewcommand{\thefigure}`  and `\setcounter` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se.

Comment: Do you mean that the 5th figure should say `3c`, and the 6th figure should say `4`, etc?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of combinations you tried and describe a little more detailed what you want to accomplish.

Comment: yes, exactly.  Q2: In the preamble I have \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{.1in}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\figc}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig. I.}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}  Then when I got past 1,2,3,4,5,6 I needed 7abc so I used

Comment: \renewcommand}{\thefigure}{7a} and same for b and c, which worked. But then I tried \setcounter}{\thefigure]{8} and got an error message: "No counter '10' defined." I could do \renewcommand]{\thefigure}{8} which works but there are 150 figures.

Comment: You need `\setcounter{figure}{8}` and also `\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}`. `\thefigure` is the representation of the `figure` counter.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `\renewcommand\thefigure{..}` *inside* `figure` environments and `\setcounter{figure}{..}` and `\addtocounter{figure}{..}` directives *outside* the `figure` environments should do the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
% be sure to remove the '[ht!]' placement specifiers in your real doc.

\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 1
\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 2
\begin{figure}[ht!] \renewcommand\thefigure{3a}\caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 3a
\begin{figure}[ht!] \renewcommand\thefigure{3b}\caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 3b
\begin{figure}[ht!] \renewcommand\thefigure{3c}\caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 3c
\setcounter{figure}{3} % b/c 'figure' counter has advanced to '5' in the meantime
\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 4
\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 5
\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 6
\addtocounter{figure}{3} % skip over three numbers
\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 10
\begin{figure}[ht!] \caption{\dots} \end{figure} % 11

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico!! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no regular pattern in the numbering, you can make a master list and use it as a lookup table, and load it into an expl3 property list to save keystrokes.

[image: lof]

[image: images]

In case things change and you need to resynchronize the master list, you can put the actual figure number in the caption to help.

For a large number of figures, a spreadsheet is efficient, reducing each master list edit to half a dozen keystrokes.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_ap_figlabel_prop

\NewDocumentCommand \loadalist { +m } {
        \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn
                \g_ap_figlabel_prop
                { #1 }
}


\NewDocumentCommand \getfiglabel { m } {
   \tl_set:Nx
   \l_tmpa_tl
   { #1 }
        \exp_args:NNo
    \prop_item:Nn
                \g_ap_figlabel_prop
                { \l_tmpa_tl }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff



\newcommand\testfig{\begin{figure}\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\caption{A caption (seq: \arabic{figure})}\end{center}\end{figure}}


\loadalist{1=1
,2=2
,3=3a
,4=3b
,5=3c
,6=4
,7=5
,8=6
,9=10
,10=11
,11=23
,12=52
}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\getfiglabel{\arabic{figure}}}

%========================================
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\testfig
\testfig
\testfig
\testfig
\testfig
\testfig
\end{document}
```

Or do:

`\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\getfiglabel{\arabic{figure}} (\arabic{figure})}`

for even more compactness.